# std::map {'0',0} pair causes logic error when the char '0' is used as a lookup

Tags: c++, logic, stdmap

I have created a function that uses a map of char and ints so that when a number is passed as a string I can check each character to make sure it's an int.  I then take that string and convert it to a pure int.  For some reason when it checks '0' it throws a false when it is found.  I know there are better ways of doing this and I have implemented many in my larger program.  This is a purely academic question as to what is happening.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Logic {

public:
    Logic();
    std::map <char, int> IsNumber;
    bool CheckForInterger(std::string);
    int StringToInt(std::string);
};


Logic::Logic() {
    IsNumber = { { '0',0 },{ '1',1 },{ '2',2 },{ '3',3 },{ '4',4 },{ '5',5 },
    { '6',6 },{ '7',7 },{ '8',8 },{ '9',9 } };
}

bool Logic::CheckForInterger(std::string word) {
    for (char character : word) {
        if (IsNumber[character]) {
            //do nothing and check next char
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "\n\"" << character << "\" is not a Number.\n\n";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int Logic::StringToInt(std::string word) {
    int number;
    number = std::stoi(word, nullptr, 10);
    return number;
}

int main() {
    Logic ThisRound;
    bool notint;
    bool quit = false;
    std::string newnumber;
    do {
        do {
            std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, newnumber);
            std::cout << std::endl;
            notint = ThisRound.CheckForInterger(newnumber);
        } while (notint);
        int newint = ThisRound.StringToInt(newnumber);
        std::cout << "Your int is: " << newint << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter Another y/n: ";
        std::string choice;
        std::getline(std::cin, choice);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        quit = (choice == "y") ? true : false;
    } while (quit);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `IsNumber[character]` returns `0` for `'0'`, does `0` evaluate to `true`? Think twice.

Comment: Also what happens if word contains non digits? Where would IsNumber['a'] points to?

Comment: @Uri Brecher it points to nothing and will tell you it is not a number.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ if it sees the second then it would not evaluate to true.  The way I understand this is that it is more if IsNumber[character] exists otherwise how would 1-9 evaluate to true?

Comment: an std::map::operator[] will create a new key pair inside that map if the key is not already in the map

Comment: @Wes The way you understood this is wrong To test for existence of a key use `std::map::find()`.

Comment: Any idea what the down vote was for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `map::operator[]` for a given `key` returns the value associated with it. Thus, for `isNumber['0']` it returns `0` and for `isNumber['5']` returns `5`, etc. In the context of `if` statement, any nonzero value is treated as `true` and zero is `false`.

If the `map::operator[]` cannot find `key`, it creates a new entry with a default constructor of the value type. In your case, `isNumber['a']` will create a new entry in your `IsNumber` map with a default value 0. Thus, `isNumber['a']` and `isNumber['0']` become indistinguishable (without further modifications to `IsNumber`)

What you probably want to do instead, is to merely check if a given key is in the map and not modify the map if it fails. For that, you want to use `map::find()` function instead. It returns a `map::iterator` to the element it found, or a value `map::end()` if it fails. Thus you can write:

```
if (IsNumber.find(character) != IsNumber.end() ) {
        //do nothing and check next char
}
```

Comment: This makes sense.  I didn't even think about it adding new entries to the map but that is exactly what it is doing.  Purely a noobie mistake.  This function originally used a string that was {0123456789} and I did char by char comparison.  Learned about map and converted it, later converted it again to isdigit().

Answer (score 2):

You should just use `isdigit(character)` instead of `IsNumber[character]`.  There's no need for the `IsNumber` map at all.

Comment: I do use isdigit() in my project.  This was a build and learn, refactor learn, refactor some more project.  This problem was just nagging me.